# xcode only running 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hello I am working on a tutorial, but it seems that I am stuck when I try to develop for all iphones (portrait only). I've tried adding constraints, but it doesn't seem like it is resizing for other iphones. It stays on the 3.5 iphone screen size and just adds more padding to the top and bottom.

In the preview it looks fine? I don't know what's wrong.
I've tried different simulators just to see if I get the same effect?

[image: The simulator and what it's suppose to look like? (I thought)]

[image: Seems like iphone 5s simulator has the same problem]

[image: The right side is what it's suppose to look like]

Comment: Do you have properly-sized launch images set for every display size?

Comment: @AstroCB could you explain in more detail what you mean by that? A lot of them are text

Comment: In your Images.xcassets file, you should have launch images set for every display size to turn off auto-scaling.

Comment: Yes I do have images for each screen retina and 2x and 1x